# Cannot get two plots showing at same time (ipython)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

Am trying to get both of these plots to show up stacked in a window, but only the last one is showing up:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
 
ax1.scatter(t5['p'], t5['F1'], color='red')
ax1.scatter(t5['r'], t5['F1'], color='blue')
plt.show()
```

This HAD been working, until the other day when I was futzing around with trying to get Seaborn plots to show up in the same plot (using the switch `--pylab`; and other settings when starting my ipython interpreter). I'm using ipython (now without any switch):

Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

This is very strange, almost like something is permanently cached and preventing me from doing this. Again, it HAD been working, but for the life of me, I cannot get it to print both scatter plots at the same time.

Comment: Have you checked the data still exist? You may have done something to trash the data.

Comment: Yes! The data were messed up so they printed the same thing (so they t5.r was the same as t5.p)... funny, since I *thought* I had checked that. I'm now able to get both on the same scatterplot, which is what I originally wanted, anyway.

Comment: do you expect two figures, or two series on one figure?

Comment: Both, actually. In any case my data got screwed up (figured this out AFTER posting this, of course :-).